# Kendo grid cell editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I want to manually edit a cell and and based on that entered data, automatically display content on another cell.

For Eg:
If quantity is changed, Total should be calculated (price * quantity) and display the result on Total column

[image]

Is it possible using Kendo grid? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible. You can find some information on internet if you search for "KendoUI Grid calculated field".

The solution depends on the type of edition mode that you have chosen ("inline", "incell" or "popup"). Since I'm not seeing any column in your grid with a button for triggering the edition, I'll understand that you are editing `incell`.  Then the solution is intercept the `save` event and compute the field as that.

Let have your `DataSource` defined as:

```
var ds = {
    data    : [
        { Id: 1, ItemName: "Galaxy", Price: "25000", Qty: 2, Total: 50000 },
        { Id: 1, ItemName: "Lumia", Price: "18000", Qty: 1, Total: 18000 },
        { Id: 1, ItemName: "Experia", Price: "10000", Qty: 3, Total: 30000 } 
    ],
    schema  : {
        model: {
            id : "Id",
            fields: {
                Id       : { type: 'number' },
                ItemName : { type: 'string' },
                Price    : { type: 'number' },
                Qty      : { type: 'number' },
                Total    : { type: 'number', editable: false }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then your Grid should be something like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    editable  : "incell",
    pageable  : false,
    columns   :
    [
        { field: "ItemName", title: "Item Name" },
        { field: "Price", title: "Price" },
        { field: "Qty", title: "Qty" },
        { field: "Total", title: "Total" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

What you need to add to `Grid` definition is the `save` event handler that check which field has changed using `e.values` (where `e` is the event information received by `save`) and compute the new `Total` and set it using `set` method on the model.

```
    save : function (e) {
        if (e.values && (e.values.Qty || e.values.Price)) {
            var qty = e.values.Qty || e.model.Qty;
            var price = e.values.Price || e.model.Price;
            e.model.set("Total", price * qty);
        }
    }
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/qA8QX/

Answer (score 0):

if you're using kendo MVC sort of the same way fo doing it:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(p => p.ItemName);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Qty);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Price);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Total);

                      columns.Command(command =>
                      {
                          command.Edit();
                      })

                  })
                  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))

                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
                      .Ajax()
                      .Model(model =>
                      {
                          model.Id(x => x.ExchangeRateId);
                          model.Field(x => x.Total).Editable(false);

                      })
                      .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Products"))
                      .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Products"))
                 )
            )
```

and in your controller something like this:

```
public class Productscontroller {
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
        var products = proxy.GetProducts();

        DataSourceResult result = products.ToDataSourceResult(request, ProductsModel => new ProductsModel()
        {
            id = products.id,
            ItemName= products.ItemName,
            Qty= products.Qty,
            Price = products.Price,
            total = products.Qty * products.Price
        });
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, ProductsModel product)
        {
        var products = proxy.GetProductById(product.Id);

        Proxy<Products>.Update(products);
    }
}
```

hope this helps